# Is there or will there be any written reasoned decision in the preliminary issue ruling of Kirsty Ayre on protection of opposition to CRT?

Tags: england-and-wales, discrimination, equality-act-2010, philosophical-belief

Judge Kirsty Ayre in the employment tribunal has ruled that ACAS employee Sean Corby’s oppositions to critical race theory are a protected philosophical belief under the equality act 2010.

Where can one, or where will one be able to, read the reasoning behind her judgment? Is it possible to say if one exists, or whether it will be published?

Comment: As always explanations from down voters will be appreciated and helpful if not anticipated.

Comment: Agreed. I'm upvoting just to offset.

Comment: I didn't down vote you. It took seconds to find. Did you try? I just did a web search for your question title, clicked through to the first link: Personnel Today. This article links to the judgement.

Comment: @Seekinganswers Have you ever read what the downvote button reads? "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful." - This shows little to no research effort **at all** like many other questions you pose. In fact, it is abundantly clear that you don't seem to have googled it. Other users found it by googling. We are **not** a replacement for google.

Comment: @Lag thanks.  I in fact, in this case, had done  a number of web searches before asking, both before and after the article you mentioned was published. However, even having read it, I had not noticed that the judgment was linked therefrom. Furthermore I had also searched on the tribunal decisions database for the parties’ name and that of the judge without avail. I suppose it was an oversight.

Comment: @Seekinganswers but the question doesn't show that effort

Comment: Okay well the view has been expressed by senior users here before in the past that most of the users here probably won’t care if I don’t make an effort to find an answer to a question myself before posting it here. Everyone learns and stores information in different ways and nobody is forced to engage with any questions here that they find uninteresting

Answer (score 1):

It’s now available on a third party outlet’s website here: https://www.personneltoday.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/8/2023/09/2023-09-13_EJ-Ayre-Corby-vs-ACAS.pdf